# Include predictor at t when including that same predictor at t-1?

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, panel-data, lags

I am very confused about whether I need to include the predictor at *t* when I also include the predictor at *t-1* in a linear mixed effects model.

For example, consider this simple model:
$$DV = \beta_0 + \beta_{1}X_{t-1}$$

Do I need to include the predictor at *t* as well in this case?
$$DV = \beta_0 + \beta_{1}X_{t-1} + \beta_{2}X_t$$

Comment: It is "fine" but the main issue is what is the time you are going to do be doing the prediction. $t$ or $t+1$ ?

Comment: @usεr11852 the DV is at $t$